# Cannot Display images using Mediaoutput

Tags: image, richfaces

While using the latest version of richfaces 4.3.5 , mediaoutput used to throw a specific error

> SEVERE: Input error for deserialize data java.io.InvalidClassException: Unauthorized deserialization attempt; org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression at org.richfaces.util.LookAheadObjectInputStream.resolveClass

Every time mediaoutput of richfaces was called, it threw the exception and the image was never displayed.

Comment: You're probably looking at [RF-13266](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13266), though it's marked as resolved. Can you update your question with more information on the environment you used and the class/xhtml that's causing the error?